# Showing data routinely using PHP

Tags: php, loops, infinite-loop

I want to routinely do something using PHP.

For example, imagine that each 5 seconds I want to display something:

```
    while(true) {
        sleep(5);
        echo "Test!";
    }
```

But this won't work because it's an infinite loop.

So, what would be the correct way to do this?

This is only a simplification of what I want to do, I would like to extract data from a file every time it changes and insert it into a SQLite database, but understanding how to do the previous example correctly would help me a lot. I don't know if there is a better way to do this instead of using PHP, so please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you doing this in a command line script ?

Comment: I'm doing this in a php file inside my web root directory.

Comment: I meant do you run it through a web browser, or in comand line ? In the first case, you may have the impression that it doesn't work because PHP it buffering output; try adding `flush();` after echo. However running this in the browser would not be the correct way to do this.

Comment: So the correct way to do this would be executing it trough the command line, something like this: `php -f C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a cron job to call your script periodically? I understand it's the most common way to do it. The minimum granularity would be each minute, though...

Comment: My understanding is that cron jobs only work on linux, I'm in a Windows machine. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Windows also has scheduled jobs

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Ignore my previous answer.  I believe cron would be the easiest way to go about it.

If you're working on a windows server this will help: http://drupal.org/node/31506